# Set specific property in array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set a specific property in a static array with no luck. The array I'm working with is in the code below. Its the default mime types array that WordPress returns. How would I to if I for example want to change the value `'image/gif'` of the property `'gif'`?

Code:

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    //Creating a new array will reset the allowed filetypes
    $mime_types = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
        'tif|tiff' => 'image/tiff'
    );
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Can i do something like if arr['gif'] == 'image/gif'?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like:

```
// functions.php
function my_myme_types($mime_types){

    $mime_types['gif'] = 'your new value';

    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```